# Set highlight background color for ASP Classic

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor

Is there anyway to display a background color when you open a page in HTML (ASP) applying this color only in ASP code, same as Notepad + +?

Notepad:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. it's realy simple:

Just add this on your color scheme:

```
<dict>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>punctuation.section.embedded.begin.asp</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#000000</string>
                <key>background</key>
                <string>#FFCC00</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>punctuation.section.embedded.end.asp</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#000000</string>
                <key>background</key>
                <string>#FFCC00</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>

        <dict>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>source.asp.embedded.html</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#ffffff</string>
                <key>background</key>
                <string>#326f76</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```